Why does a strictly affinoid space have a special fiber?
This is a soft and possibly naive question: I am confused by the relation between formal geometry and Berkovich analytic spaces. Roughly speaking, the latter should describe generic fibers of the former. What confuses me is how the special fiber of a strictly affinoid algebra fits into this picture.
Let $A = L^o[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$ be a flat algebra over the field $L$ with a non-archimedian valuation, defining a model $\mathcal{X}$. The completion of $A$ along the special fiber defines a formal scheme, described by the completion $H = L^o\langle x_1, \dots, x_n \rangle /\langle I \rangle$ of $A$ along $I$. The generic fiber $\mathcal{A} = H\otimes L = L\langle x_1, \dots, x_n \rangle /\langle I \rangle$ is a strictly affinoid algebra.
Now on the one hand we have the special fiber $H \otimes \widetilde{L} = H/L^{oo}H$, which by construction of $H$ agrees with the special fiber $A\otimes \widetilde{L}$.
On the other hand we can consider the ring of power-bounded elements $\mathcal{A}^o = \{ a \in \mathcal{A} \ \mid \  ||a|| \leq 1\}$ which is an algebra over $L^\circ$. There is a natural map $A \otimes \widetilde{L} \longrightarrow \mathcal{A}^\circ \otimes\widetilde{L}$.
My question is the following: What is the geometric meaning of the special fiber $\mathcal{A}^\circ \otimes\widetilde{L}$ and the above map?
Many thanks!

In good situations it's an isomorphism on the reduced quotients (e.g., if $L$ is a reasonable field such as discretely valued or algebraically closed). For some certain wild fields $L$, $\mathcal{A}^\circ$ can be quite ill-behaved as a formal $L^\circ$-scheme (e.g., it needn't be topologically finitely generated). Are you willing to restriction to reasonable fields?

Dear Alex, many thanks!
I would be interested in the case where the base field is real closed.
For example the field of real Puiseux series, or its completion.


Proposition: Let $L$ be a non-archimedean field which is

stable (see [BGR, §3.6]),
such that $|L^\times|$ is divisible.

Then, the map  $$A\otimes \tilde{L}\to
 \mathcal{A}^\circ\otimes\tilde{L},$$ induces an isomorphism on reduced quotients

Example: The conditions on $L$ hold if $L$ is the field of (completed) real Puiseux series over $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, the residue field is of characteristic $0$ so stable by [BGR, §3.6, Proposition 13]. Moreover, as $|L^\times|=\mathbb{Q}$, it also have divisible value group. $\blacksquare$
To prove this proposition, for an affinoid $L$-algebra $\mathcal{C}$, let us write $\tilde{\mathcal{C}}=\mathcal{C}^\circ/\mathcal{C}^{\circ\circ}$. One then observes that the map $\mathcal{C}^\circ\otimes \tilde{L}\to \tilde{\mathcal{C}}$ induces an isomorphism on reduced quotients -- it's evidently surjection with kernel consisting of nilpotents.
Proof: The claim is insensitive to replacing $\mathcal{A}$ by its reduced quotient, so we may assume without loss of generality that $\mathcal{A}$ is reduced. Moreover, we see from the above discussion that it suffices to show that the map $A\otimes \breve{L}\to \tilde{A}$ induces an isomorphism on reductive quotients. This map evidently has kernel consisting of nilpotent elements, and so it suffices to show it's surjective. Let $f_i$ be the images of $x_i$ under the natural map $A\otimes\tilde{L}\to\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$. Set $\mathcal{B}=L\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$. Then, one has the natural surjection $\mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{A}$. By our assumptions we then see from [BGR, §6.4.2, Proposition 1] that the map $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}\to \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ is surjective, But it's easy to see that $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}=\tilde{L}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and that the map $\tilde{L}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ sends $x_i$ to $f_i$. So, the conclusion follows. $\blacksquare$

Many many thanks!
Could you remind me of the source, so I can cite it?

@Kemal Bosch, Guntzer, and Remmert.

Thank you for reminding me.
